# Xcode 6: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

I keep getting this error when I run my program in Xcode:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet var textFielD: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var message: UILabel!

@IBAction func guessButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var numberOfFingers = arc4random() % 6

    println(numberOfFingers)

    var numberOfFingersString = String(numberOfFingers)


    if (numberOfFingersString == textFielD.text!) {

        message.text = "You got it right!"

    } else {

        message.text = "Nope! I was holding up \(numberOfFingers) fingers. Try again!"

    }
```

I am working in Xcode 6.1.1 (the most recent version) on an iMac running Yosemite.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It is probably from textField.text! Take off the exclamation. you might have to reconnect your outlets and/or ibactions

Comment: You will get this error if the optional (might be nil) value you're unwrapping (!) is nil.  test to be sure it is not nil before you unwrap it.

Answer (score 3):

Either `textFielD` (note 'spelling' error) or `message` is not linked in Interface Builder.  Check that all outlets are bound.  `IBOutlets` are always declared as implicitly unwrapped optionals - you need to bind them in Interface Builder or in `viewDidLoad` (or a similarly early method).